# How to configure two AUTH_USER_MODEL in Django Authentication

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm using django's authentication to login users. But I have two models from where `authenticate` method would check the user credentials. One is `ApplicationUser` and the other is `SystemUser` I have made one of them and it works fine like so:

**models.py**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username and password.
        """
        ....
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):        
        ...
        return user


class ApplicationUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    application_user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ....
    ....
```

**views.py**

```
def login_view(request):
     ...
     user = authenticate(username = email, password = password)
     if user is not None:
         ...
         login(request, user)
         ....
         ....
```

I came through this problem and got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253842/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-multiple-auth-user-model-in-django-1-5) but I couldn't work out a solution to this.

**My Questions:**

1. How do I specify two `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, as of yet I have set
   `ApplicationUser` as `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.
2. And even if I somehow specify
       the two `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, how do the `authenticate` or `login` function
       know where (`ApplicationUser` or `SystemUser`) to match the credentials and create session for the user
       accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py set

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.YouCustomUserModel'
```

Then let's django do the rest.

If you want to have others User Model, you need to extend them from your selected `AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Comment: I have already done that with `ApplicationUser` which is my CustomUserModel. How would I specify that for `SystemUser` also?

Comment: @Sibtain you can have only one auth model, if you want others models derived from your main UserModel, you need extend your AUTH USER MODEL.

Comment: Can you give a rough example for that?

Comment: @Sibtain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django